# NextJS/Typescript/Apollo error; property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, apollo, strapi

I'm fairly new to NextJS and Typescript and I’m implementing the headless CMS Strapi, but am having issues using Apollo. I’ve searched google all weekend to try and understand this issue better. I'm hoping someone can help me out here.

#### Error

Receiving the following Error in my `_app.tsx`

```shell
Property 'apollo' does not exist on type 'AppPropsType<Router, {}>'.
```

The error is occuring on my `MyApp` function below.

#### My `_app.tsx`

```ts
import * as React from 'react'
import { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import withData from '../../utils/apollo'

import 'circular-std'
import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css'
import '../scss/styles.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, apollo }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}

export default withData(MyApp)
```

Corresponding [Strapi setup tutorial here](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-with-next-react-js-strapi-and-apollo#frontendsetup) under section 3 of Front-end Setup.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, I've done the following:

```
import App, { AppProps  } from 'next/app';
import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client';

interface Props {
  apollo: ApolloClient<{}>;
}

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps, apollo }: AppProps & Props) => {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is telling you, correctly, that `AppProps` from NextJS does not have an `apollo` property because NextJS does not know anything about apollo. Apollo is a different library.

To set up `ApolloProvider` you need [create your client as described in the Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/). Something like this:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://48p1r2roz4.sse.codesandbox.io',
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Klas, looking more into it now!